# How to iterate through dates in ascending order in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

My dataframe look like:

```
id    date                   count
1     2011-01-01 00:00:10      10
1     2011-01-01 00:00:11      12
2     2013-02-02 00:00:01      2
1     2011-01-01 00:00:12      4
2     2014-02-01 00:00:20      6
```

How do I iterate through date in ascending order

```
for id, frame in df.groupby('id'):
     count_list = []
     for item in frame.sort_values(by='date',ascending=True):
         count_list.append(item['count'])
```

My expected result is : `[[10, 12, 4], [2, 6]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just sort by `date` (as long as this is a proper `datetime` Series), then groupby `ID`, and transform to list:

```
# If not already proper date:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df.sort_values(['date']).groupby('id')['count'].apply(list).tolist()

# [[10, 12, 4], [2, 6]]
```